# Local bootstrap,css,js file not work

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Link works fine in my project. As, all time I have not internet access I download the file from the above link and put in that folder where the page is stayed. But, then they don't work as before.
I do

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Edit** 
My folder structure

```
auctionDetails.php        carousel.html  delete.html           navbar.html         README.md          signupSuccessful.html
auction.php               carousel.php   font-awesome.min.css  newnavbar.php       search.php         style.css
bootstrap-4.1.0-dist.zip  cart.php       footer.html           popper.min.js       signinnavbar.html  test1.html
bootstrap.min.css         cow.jpeg       insertLike.php        productDetails.css  signIn.php         test.php
bootstrap.min.js          database.php   jquery-3.3.1.js       productDetails.php  signUp.php
```

**Edit2**
After solve some missing jquery it works. But, font-awesome doesn't work yet.

[font-awesome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YG8n.png)

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure

Comment: @patelarpan see edited question. I put folder structure.

Comment: Can check on console. Any 404 error

Comment: Define *they don't work as before*?

Comment: Please check browser console.

Comment: Also `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` != `jquery-3.3.1.js`

Comment: I don't see jquery-3.3.1.min.js in your folder structure. Did you include the minified file?

Comment: And where are the fonts etc

Comment: Based to your structure, where your `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and `popper.min.js`? what file you call bootstrap from? `acution.php`? **EDIT:** sorry, `popper.min.js` exists, the problem is jQuery

Comment: Use the degbugger in your browser, F12 will show you where it's failing to find those files.

Comment: jquery works now, but font-awesome not works.

Comment: Because there is no fonts folder for fontawesome

Comment: You forgot to put fonts folder

Comment: @patelarpan I don't know about font folder. Please describe

Comment: With fontawesome CSS you also need font folder

Comment: @patelarpan From where I download it?

Comment: Form here https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/

Comment: @patelarpan Yes this works. You can write an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's great

Comment: Answer added. Check out.

Comment: Please upvote my answers if it's help you

Comment: @patelarpan I accept your answer. But, I can't upvote because my reputation is less 15.

Comment: No problem. Next time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thire is no fonts folder in your folder structure so you need to download font awesome icon form  [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)

**Extra tip**: put css and js in different folder that help you alot when project goes bigger

Answer (score 0):

open the console in your browser and on the "Network" tab make your sure your files are loading.

Don't forget to keep styles inside the head and scripts inside the footer.